# Does aircraft manufacturers provide option to exchange older models?

Tags: commercial-aviation, airbus, boeing, cost

Most of the vehicle manufacturers provide exchange value for older models when buying a newer one. Like you can exchange your old BMW 3 Series for new 3 Series or upgrade to 5 Series and so on.

Is there any similar offering provided by aircraft manufacturers to update, something like upgrade 747's to 777's?

Comment: The difference is that individual auto trade-ins are motivated by buyer perceptions of status, style, &c.  Airlines are more likely to be motivated by practical factors such as operating & maintenance costs, so would be less likely to trade, and the trade-ins would be worth less, as a percentage of new cost.

Comment: Further, automobile trade-in is offered by the *dealer* in order to incentivize sales to people who have a running car.  You won't get this if you're buying directly from the manufacturer.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Carmakers actively participate in the used car trade: they sponsor leases to generate a stock of used cars, they have repurchase agreements with rental fleets, they have certified pre-owned programs which apply a factory warranty. 

What's also not comparable is that aircraft are sold under the razor blade model: a lot of the profits come from spares and support. An older airframe can produce more profits than a new one. The 737MAX groundings caused GE to increase profits, as it kept older engines in service and they didn't have to take the hit on new ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Manufacturers will do whatever it takes to score an order, so it's not uncommon for an OEM to take old aircraft on trade with a new order, especially if they are from the same maker.  The OEM I worked for had a used aircraft sales division that was mainly used to unload trade-ins.

Comment: Many of your budget airlines are flying previously-leased (ie, used) aircraft around. 737's, 747's, airbus variants, etc. Leasing seems to be what many/most airlines do these days anyway, which gives them more flexibility to "trade up" to newer models as they become available.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Even non-budget airlines frequently do that to some extent. Delta used to be particularly notorious for snapping up lightly or moderately-used aircraft that fit in well with their existing fleet when they were available at bargain prices. Their entire 717 fleet (which is the world's largest by a wide margin) came that way, for example, when Southwest bought AirTran, but wanted to maintain their 737-only strategy. Even the future Air Force One aircraft were acquired from Boeing at bargain prices as white tails (not technically used, but abandoned orders.)